# Amplify w/Cognito: How do I get the Current User's Email?

Tags: javascript, amazon-cognito, aws-amplify

I am using AWS Amplify, with Cognito for user Auth.

Users go into a user pool, and register and sign in just with email address and password.

When a user that has signed in through Cognito navigates to a certain page, I want to be retrieve their email address. How can I do this?

I am able to retrieve some user data with this code (I am using javascript/Angular):

```
import Auth from '@aws-amplify/auth';
...

ngOnInit(){
  Auth.currentAuthenticatedUser().then((user)=>{
        console.log('user = ' + JSON.stringify(user.pool))      
 })
}
```

The email does appear on the response, but I haven't yet been able to isolate the email from the returned JSON.

I've tried going through the docs, but I haven't yet found info on stuff like the attribute options I can add to `currentAuthenticatedUser()`, or if there is another method that is cleaner (which I assume there is).

**EDIT: It looks like the following works:**

```
Auth.currentAuthenticatedUser().then((user) => {
  console.log('user email = ' + user.attributes.email);
});
```

But I am still hoping to understand the documentation better. I found this solution in a random github question, not the official docs. Where would I find this solution in the AWS Amplify / Cognito documentation?

Comment: it would help if you posted the structure of the JSON, and change any data you don't want shown to us.

Comment: I'm actually thinking that currentAuthenticatedUser is not necessarily the right way to do this--I just haven't yet found an alternative. The JSON data returned is not the clean JSON I would expect from whatever the proper method is. My hope is that this is a fairly common requirement and there is a cleaner way to do it.

Answer (score 4):

```js
    import cognito from "../path/to/your/config/cognito.json";
    import Amplify, { Auth, Hub } from 'aws-amplify';
    ...
    ...


    useEffect(() => {
        Amplify.configure({ Auth: cognito });
        Hub.listen('auth', ({ payload: { event, data } }) => {
            switch (event) {
                case 'signIn':
                    console.log('Event name -> ', event, data)
                    // here is your name, email e.t.c.
                    console.log(data.signInUserSession.idToken.payload);
                    break
                case 'signOut':
                    console.log('sign out')
                    // this.setState({ user: null })
                    break
                default:
                    console.log('Unhandled use case - ' + event)
            }
        })
    }, [])
```

Answer (score 2):

You can check [this one](https://docs.amplify.aws/lib/auth/manageusers/q/platform/js#retrieve-current-authenticated-user) from the official documentation

and enable read access
***General settings -> App clients -> Show details -> Set attribute read and write permissions link***

and then to make sure you are fetching the updated attributes

```
Auth.currentAuthenticatedUser({ bypassCache: true })
```

Comment: Yep, this is what did it for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
Auth.currentSession()
    .then((data) => {
       // this data has user details in accessToken
    }).catch(err => console.log(err));
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import { Auth } from 'aws-amplify';

Auth.currentAuthenticatedUser({
  bypassCache: false // Optional, By default is false. If set to true, this call will send a request to Cognito to get the latest user data
})
  .then((user) => console.log(user))
  .catch((err) => console.log(err));
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a hook I wrote that works well:

```
import { Dispatch, SetStateAction, useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { Auth, Hub } from "aws-amplify";


export interface UserDetailsT {
    username: string,
    email: string,
    emailVerified: boolean,
};


const useAuth = (): [UserDetailsT | null, Dispatch<SetStateAction<UserDetailsT | null>>] => {
    const [userDetails, setUserDetails] = useState<UserDetailsT | null>(null);
    
    useEffect(() => {
        const getUserDetails = async () => {
            try {
                if (userDetails === null) {
                    const { username, attributes } = await Auth.currentAuthenticatedUser() || null;
                    setUserDetails({
                        username,
                        email: attributes?.email,
                        emailVerified: attributes?.email_verified
                    });
                }
            } catch {
                setUserDetails(null);
            }
        }

        getUserDetails();
        Hub.listen('auth', () => getUserDetails());

    }, [Auth, userDetails, setUserDetails]);

    return [userDetails, setUserDetails];
};


export default useAuth;
```

Answer (score -4):

The following works for me after the user is logged in...

```
import { Auth, Amplify } from 'aws-amplify'

console.log(Auth.user.attributes.email)
```

Comment: Gnerally not advised. The `user` property on the `Auth` class is marked as a private variable, and cannot be reliably accessed directly.